# Can't get subl command to work in OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext3

I'm trying to get the subl comand for sublime text 3 to work on the terminal command line but after trying out a few things I can't get it working.

```
$ sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/.
$ subl
-bash: subl: command not found
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I susspect it has something to do with my `$path`, should I set something up in my `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's odd. It works for me fine. Your path is already looking in /usr/local/bin so that shouldn't be a problem. However I have version 2. I can't see how that would be a problem. I see that i have backslashes for the spaces in the link command;

```
    sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/.
```

Try that.